# How can I append multiple lists of strings to a key in dictionary when the key is the second value of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I have

```
data = [['Sea', 'Blue', 'Fish', 'Swim'], 
    ['Bored', 'Annoyed', 'Frustrated', 'Done'], 
    ['Keyboard', 'Blue', 'Desktop', 'Mouse']]
```

I need to have the function to return

```
{'Blue': [['Sea', 'Fish', 'Swim'], ['Keyboard', 'Desktop', 'Mouse']],    
    'Annoyed': [['Bored', 'Frustrated, 'Done']]}
```

I have this function I made

```
def func():
    b = dict()
    for element in data:
        for i in element:
                if i[1] in b:
                    b[i[1]].append(i[0], i[2], i[3])
                else:
                    b[i[1]] = (i[0], i[2], i[3])
```

But it returns:

```
builtins.IndexError: string index out of range
```

I hope this made sense, thank you in advance

Comment: Which one is the constant here? Position of these elements or their values?

Comment: It would help to describe the algorithm explicitly in words.  I was able to figure it out by reading through your code, but it's not at all obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting too many loops. `element` is already the inner list like `['Sea', 'Blue', 'Fish', 'Swim'`, etc. `i` is therefore the characters of the string.

There are some other problems, see the comments below:

```
def func():
    b = dict()
    for element in data:
        if element[1] in b:
            b[element[1]].append([element[0], element[2], element[3]]) # append takes one argument
        else:
            b[element[1]] = [[element[0], element[2], element[3]]]  # list, not tuple
    return b
```

Comment: You're concatenating the lists, but as I read the OP's output the goal is to append, not extend.